PowerShell -> The directories with NTFS group permissions only. Error
I am trying to make this script work but I am getting error:
"Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'."
This script should only export directories that have only AD groups as NTFS permissions (without AD account - S-1-5-21).
# Basispfad, unter dem die Verzeichnisse durchsucht werden sollen
$basePath = "C:\PfadZuIhremVerzeichnis"

# Pfad und Dateiname der CSV-Datei
$csvExportPath = "C:\PfadZumSpeichern\DirectoriesWithGroupOnlyPermissions.csv"

# Sammelt Informationen über Verzeichnisse
$results = @()

# Funktion, die überprüft, ob nur Gruppenberechtigungen vorhanden sind
function HasOnlyGroupPermissions {
    param ([string]$path)

    $acl = Get-Acl -Path $path
    foreach ($access in $acl.Access) {
        if (-not $access.IsInherited -and ($access.IdentityReference.ToString() -notmatch '^S-1-5-21.*\\[^\\]+$')) {
            # Es handelt sich um eine direkte Berechtigung, die nicht einer Gruppe zugeordnet ist.
            return $false
        }
    }
    return $true
}

# Funktion, um nur Verzeichnisse bis zur gewünschten Tiefe zu erfassen
function Get-DirectoriesToDepth {
    param (
        [string]$rootPath,
        [int]$maxDepth,
        [int]$currentDepth = 0
    )

    # Basisfall: Wenn maximale Tiefe erreicht ist, stoppe die Rekursion
    if ($currentDepth -ge $maxDepth) {
        return
    }

    # Verzeichnisse auf der aktuellen Ebene finden
    $childDirs = Get-ChildItem -Path $rootPath -Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    foreach ($dir in $childDirs) {
        # Aktuelles Verzeichnis hinzufügen
        if (HasOnlyGroupPermissions -path $dir.FullName) {
            $results += [pscustomobject]@{
                Path = $dir.FullName
            }
        }
        # Rekursiver Aufruf für die nächste Ebene
        Get-DirectoriesToDepth -rootPath $dir.FullName -maxDepth $maxDepth -currentDepth ($currentDepth + 1)
    }
}

# Start der Suche
Get-DirectoriesToDepth -rootPath $basePath -maxDepth 2

# Ergebnisse in CSV exportieren
$results | Export-Csv -Path $csvExportPath -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8

Write-Host "Die Verzeichnisse mit ausschließlich Gruppenberechtigungen bis zu einer Tiefe von 2 Ebenen wurden nach '$csvExportPath' exportiert."

Do you have any idea what is wrong?
Thank you very much for your help.

Change From : $results = @()  To : $results = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()

There are some things that needs to be fixed, and some things that you can improve so I'll split them off into sections:
Scopes
You are declaring your variable $results in your main script, but you are trying to assign values to it inside your Get-DirectoriesToDepth function. By default, your variables are only accessible in the local scope, which means that the values you try to assign to the $result on line 42 will only be available inside that function. This also means that your original $results variable will never be assigned any value. What you should do here is return the values that you found so that the caller scope can access the information. For details, see the Microsoft article on About_Scopes.
Get-ChildItem with -Depth flag
I see that you only want to search down to a certain point in the folder tree. Get-ChildItem already has a -Depth flag that specifies how far down you want to go, so your recursive function can be replaced with Get-ChildItem -Depth 2.
Access Rules, string translations, and Get-ADObject
Running $Access.IdentityReference.ToString() will always return the user account on the DOMAIN\ACCOUNT format. This means that existing users will be returned as they are, and your script would only stop if it found users that no longer exist in AD. If you really only want to look at groups you will want to exclude existing users as well. To find if an AD object is a user or a group you can run Get-ADObject and look at the ObjectClass property:
$AccountNameWithoutDomain = $($Access.IdentityReference.Value -split "\\")[1]
Get-ADObject -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$AccountNameWithoutDomain'"

This example uses your $Access variable by just referencing the .Value of the IdentityReference, splitting it by the backslash to use only the account name. It then gets an AD object with that name. The returned value will look like this:
DistinguishedName                          Name      ObjectClass ObjectGUID                          
-----------------                          ----      ----------- ----------                          
CN=My User,CN=Users,DC=myad,DC=local       My User   user        ....

If the ObjectClass is 'Group' then you know it's a group. Note that Get-ADObject will return $null if the object doesn't exist, in which case we can conclude that it is going to be a local account (NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM, CREATOR OWNER etc.) unless you are running a massive multi-domain environment with mixed groups.
Putting it all together
So, what you want is to list all folders down to a specific depth, and only the folders where the permissions have only domain groups. Here is the full code with additional error handling.
# Basispfad, unter dem die Verzeichnisse durchsucht werden sollen
$basePath = "C:\PfadZuIhremVerzeichnis"

# Pfad und Dateiname der CSV-Datei
$csvExportPath = "C:\PfadZumSpeichern\DirectoriesWithGroupOnlyPermissions.csv"
$csvExportPathErrors = "C:\PfadZumSpeichern\DirectoriesWithGroupOnlyPermissions - Errors.csv"

# Sammelt Informationen über Verzeichnisse
$results = @()
$FailedToReadAcl = @()
$MaxDepth = 2

$AllFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $basePath -Depth $MaxDepth -Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

:FolderLoop foreach ($Folder in $AllFolders) {
    
    #This section stores all failed Get-Acl attempts to a separate variable (access denied etc.)
    try {
        $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        $FailedToReadAcl += [pscustomobject]@{
            Path = $Folder.FullName
        }
        continue
    }

    #Loop through all access rules for the folder
    $AddFolder = $true
    :AccessLoop foreach ($AccessRule in $Acl.Access) {
        $UsernameWithoutDomain = ($AccessRule.IdentityReference.Value -split "\\")[1]

        #NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM permissions can sometimes cause the Get-ADObject to fail, so this breaks the loop before that happens.
        if ($UsernameWithoutDomain -eq "SYSTEM") {
            $AddFolder = $false
            break AccessLoop
        }

        #If the object is NOT a security group, break the loop
        $ADObject = Get-ADObject -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$UsernameWithoutDomain'"
        if ( [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($ADObject) -or ($ADObject.ObjectClass -ne "group") ) {
            $AddFolder = $false
            break AccessLoop
        }
    }

    if ($AddFolder) {
        $results += [pscustomobject]@{
            Path = $Folder.FullName
        }
    }
}

# Ergebnisse in CSV exportieren
$results | Export-Csv -Path $csvExportPath -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
$FailedToReadAcl | Export-Csv -Path $csvExportPathErrors -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8

Write-Host "Die Verzeichnisse mit ausschließlich Gruppenberechtigungen bis zu einer Tiefe von 2 Ebenen wurden nach '$csvExportPath' exportiert."
Write-Host "All inaccessible folders were exported to the CSV file '$csvExportPathErrors'."

Hope that helps!

One thing I see... Try{}Catch{} only works on stopping errors, so using -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue will never trip the Catch scriptblock. Instead change that to -ErrorAction Stop to utilize your error handling

Oh yeah, I thought I changed that, good catch!

I have tried on my test directory and I am only getting ï»¿
in csv file.  Do you have idea why?

It could be that you don't have any folder in your test directory with only groups, but it looks like your CSV file is not using the correct encoding either. You can verify by just running $result or $FailedToReadAcl and see if those variables contain any values at all. I've solved a similar issue in my environment by deleting the CSV and letting the script create it, and also adding the -Append flag.

Problem:  The first time you use  $results += [pscustomobject]@{ Path = $dir.FullName } it converts $Results from a Array to a [PSCustomObject].
Thus += fails starting from the second loop, because its a alias method for Arrays and $results is not an Array anymore.
Solution: when you plan to modify the contents of a collection(for example by adding items), do NOT use a Array but a List.
(Note: List is preferred to ArrayList, too )
So replace:

$results=@() with $results = [System.Collections.Generic.List[PSCustomObject]]::new()
 $results += [pscustomobject]@{ Path = $dir.FullName } with $results.Add([pscustomobject]@{ Path = $dir.FullName })


That's not true. In PowerShell using += to add items to an array is functional, though not efficient (it rebuilds the array each time you do it).  Your suggestion is good general advise, but not a solution.

When doing a limited test on my system, that was the source of the Error in OP's post, and moving from Array to List solved it. What I did get wrong?

Thank you so much! :)
One thing is not as I want, it still shows me directories with AD accounts. I dont know why this is not working as it should (
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $path
foreach ($access in $acl.Access) {
if (-not $access.IsInherited -and ($access.IdentityReference.ToString() -notmatch '^S-1-5-21.*\[^\]+$')) {
# This is a direct permission that is not associated with a group.
return $false
}
}
return $true)
will not filter it. It does not work because the permissions are inherited?
